# Get the maximum value for each neighboured triangle

Tags: python, numpy, mesh

I have a mesh with triangular elements. Each element has an index. I have a function to check the neighbours, the result is as shown below.

[1, 2] for example means, that triangle 1 and triangle 2 are neighbours, same as triangle 1 and triangle 4.

```
Adjacent_Elements = ([[1, 2], [1, 4], [2, 5], [4, 3], [3, 5] ... ])
```

Now I check the change in size from one element to his neighbour. The number means the change in size ratio.

For example: for the first pair [1, 2] I get the transition value 1 which means, that they have the same size. For the next pair [1, 4], I get the value 3 which means, that the change in size from element 1 to element 4 is factor 3. For the pair [2, 5] I get the value 2, which means, that the change in size is factor 2. 
The array Element_Transition contains all those values. There is one value for every pair.

```
Element_Transition = ([1, 3, 2, 1, 1.5, ...])
```

Every Triangle has at least 1 and maximum 3 neighbours, so I get 1-3 values for every triangle. In this example, Triangle 1 changes in size by factor 1 (at [1, 2]) aswell as by factor 3 (at [1, 4]) and so on.

Here's an example picture : [image: Element Transition Factors]

Now what I need is only the **maximum** transition value for every triangle.

```
All_Trans_Values = ([[1, [1, 3]], [2, [1, 2], [3, [1, 1.5],...])
Max_Trans_Value = ([[1, 3], [2, 2], [3, 1.5], [4, 3]....])
                     ^       ^       ^         ^
                     ^       ^       ^         ^
                    these are the pairs from Adjacent_Elements
                    the second number is always the maximum transition value
```

or just the value

```
Value = ([3, 2, 1.5, 3, ...])
```

Is there a way to compute that? It's for quality researches inside of triangulated meshes. I need only the "bad" ( = big ) numbers.

Comment: I don't understand your setup here. What do you mean by "Those numbers are referenced to the indexes from Adjacent_Elements before" - referenced how? Also, what do the elements in `Trans_Value` mean? For example the `[1,3]`, what do those numbers mean? And is `Value` just a list of the second element of each member of `Trans_Value`?

Comment: I edited my post, is it more understandable now?  [1, 3] means, that the element (or triangle) 1s maximum change in size to a neighbouring element (triangle) is factor 3. Yes, Value is just the second part of Trans_Value

Comment: It's definitely better than it was before, but there are still some things I'm not clear on. For example what do the numbers in `All_Trans_Values` mean? What is `Adjacent_Faces`? I still don't think it's particularly well explained what `Max_Trans_Value` is, but that's probably mostly due to the ambiguity in `All_Trans_Values`.

Comment: I tried my very best to explain it more detailed and added a picture. I misspelled Adjacent_Faces, it has to be Adjacent_Elements, sorry.

Comment: Hm... so, if I understand correctly, in `All_Trans_Values`, the first member of each sublist is a sequential index? And the second member is a list of all members of `Element_Transition` whose corresponding sublist in `Adjacent_Elements` includes that index? That's the main part I haven't been able to understand in the last couple edits. Now that you changed `All_Trans_Values` to group the transition values into a list of their own, it's starting to make sense, I _think_.

Comment: Yes, the first member is the index of the triangles which ranged from 1-x (depends on mesh size). The second member contains all transition factors from Element_Transition, yes. In this example, the transition factor between [1, 2] is 1, so the 1 needs to be referenced to triangles 1 and 2 (in All_Trans_Values). Between [1, 4] it's 3, so triangles 1 and 4 needs to get the value 3. In the end, I want only the biggest value for each triangle.

Comment: Can the factors be smaller then one (In your example the pair [2,5] would be 0.5)?

Comment: No, I divided the bigger area by the smaller area, so the result is always bigger than 1

Comment: @TobiasStein have you tried my code in the edited answer? Are there problems with it? Did you find a solution yourself?

Comment: I'm still trying to verify it. It's not that easy, because I have to plot the mesh to do so. I will reply asap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand your problem after the edits better, so the old answer is only a part of solving your problem. Originally I thought you already have the values sorted to the triangles.

**New answer:**

This should do what you want.

```
Adjacent_Elements = np.array([[1,3],[1,4],[2,3],[3,4]])
Element_Transition = np.array([2,1,4,2])

# maybe you know the amount of triangles already
number_of_triangles = max(Adjacent_Elements.flatten())

# generating list of indexes
indexes = np.arange(1,number_of_triangles+1)
# generating list of zeros
zeros = np.zeros((number_of_triangles))
Max_Trans_Value = np.stack((indexes,zeros),axis=-1)

# iterating over all Adjacent_Elements with corresponding factor
for triangles,factor in zip(Adjacent_Elements,Element_Transition):
    for triangle in triangles:
        # if the factor is heigher than the currently stored one
        if factor >= Max_Trans_Value[triangle-1,1]:
            Max_Trans_Value[triangle-1,1] = factor

print(Max_Trans_Value)
# will print:
#  [[1 2],
#   [2 4],
#   [3 4],
#   [4 2]]
```

---

**Old answer:**

I guess you want to have the maximum for each of the sublists of All_Trans_Values.

I would use list comprehension and the build in `max()` function.

```
a = [[1,1,3],[2,3],[1,2,2]]
c = [max(b) for b in a]
```

c will now have all the maximum values in it.
`[3,3,2]`